# This ISS trash deployment looks more like 2 feet than 2 inches per second, was it too fast or are these articles incorrect?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, iss, reentry, orbital-maneuver

Digital Trends' [Watch a NASA astronaut jettison part of the ISS into space](https://www.digitaltrends.com/news/watch-a-nasa-astronaut-jettison-part-of-the-iss-into-space/) which was linked in  says:

> Writing in Air & Space last year about the process of jettisoning objects, veteran NASA engineer Mike Engle explained how launching decommissioned parts from the space station can be a risky process, a fact that prompted him to help create an official ISS Jettison Policy to ensure that such activities are carried out safely.
>
> “Jettisoning trash from a spacecraft is no mere stroll to a dumpster,” Engle wrote. “First and foremost, you have to make sure that whatever you throw away doesn’t come back and hit you — a frightening possibility in the weird realm of orbital mechanics.”
>
> **The engineer added, “Simple trigonometry led to the conclusion that pushing an object away at two inches per second within a 30-degree cone centered on a line directly opposite the direction that the ISS was traveling as it orbited the Earth would be enough” to send the part safely on its way.**

The same speed is mentioned in the Air and Space link it cites. From [Tossing Out Trash From the Space Station Takes More Planning Than You’d Think](https://www.airspacemag.com/space/space-junk-180973982/):

> Our idea was to have EVA astronauts manually push jettisoned items away in the direction opposite the station’s orbit. Analysis showed that a surprisingly small retrograde change in velocity was required: **only about 1 to 1.5 inches per second would ensure no recontact.** The drag of the jettisoned object would be greater than that of the ISS, further ensuring that the jettisoned object would keep moving behind and below the ISS until it eventually burned up in the atmosphere. In the case of the EAS, however, we scheduled a thruster burn to raise the ISS orbit after jettison just to make sure. Safety engineers insisted that we define a jettison “cone” to account for any directional errors, so that even if an object were at the edge of the cone, it would still fly away safely. **Simple trigonometry led to the conclusion that pushing an object away at two inches per second (a rate easily achievable by an EVA astronaut) within a 30-degree cone centered on a line directly opposite the direction that the ISS was traveling as it orbited the Earth would be enough.**

#### This seems to be a lot faster than that

In the video in this International Space Station [tweet](https://twitter.com/Space_Station/status/1354461242610642945) it looks more like two feet per second than two inches, an order of magnitude difference. I estimate that the antenna cover moves more than it's own length in one second.

> .@AstroVicGlover jettisons a science antenna cover into space since it is no longer needed. It will eventually enter Earth's atmosphere and burn up safely.

**Question:** What's the root cause of the disparity between what the article says and what's shown in the video?

Comment: I believe the 2 inches per second are the minimum required, but more than that is better, and easier to execute manually.

Comment: Essentially any speed above 2 inches per second will do... apart from 15km/s which would be a really bad idea.

Comment: you don't want to push it away fast enough to unintentionally and non-trivially increase the velocity of your space station, either - although my guess is that this is not ever a concern since the mass of the rubbish compared to the space station itself is quite small.

Comment: @user45266 they're pushing the object *backwards* which means it nudges the ISS forward. They have to bring rocket fuel from Earth regularly to burn engines to do the same thing to counteract the continuous atmospheric drag at 400 km trying to pull the ISS down, so I don't think it's a problem in this case. There are all kinds of other perturbations that affect it's orbit, as long as they can be predicted it's not a problem. btw I've just asked [How hard does atmospheric drag push on the ISS? Is it more than one pound?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50740/12102)

Comment: @asdfex " Essentially any speed above 2 inches per second will do... apart from 15km/s which would be a really bad idea. " Why is that?  Would that put the debris in an orbit opposing the ISS?

Comment: TL;DR astronauts in EVAs can basically throw objects retrograde at any decent speed and they are okay. The whole article implies that they thought they would need something to jettison stuff and doing the calculations they realized they could literally throw the garbage by hand if they were just a bit careful in the direction. Obviously then the 2 inches speed is just a lower limit... if it wasn't astronauts wouldn't be able to throw stuff at exactly at 2 inches speed! I don't think they know how fast they throw stuff around...

Comment: @MacGuffin  Exactly.  15.6km/s to be more precise, that gives the same orbit as ISS but in the opposite direction.

Comment: Plus - why is someone from NASA using non-SI units ?  NASA has mandated metric.  Is it just to be "approachable" / accessible ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> What's the root cause of the disparity between what the article says and what's shown in the video?

There is no disparity. The article says you need a *minimum* velocity of two inches per second [**bold** emphasis mine]:

> The engineer added, “Simple trigonometry led to the conclusion that pushing an object away at two inches per second within a 30-degree cone centered on a line directly opposite the direction that the ISS was traveling as it orbited the Earth **would be enough**” to send the part safely on its way.

> Analysis showed that a surprisingly small retrograde change in velocity was required: **only** about 1 to 1.5 inches per second would **ensure no recontact**.

[The word "only" can be used different ways. As I interpret the sentence, this does not mean that 1 to 1.5 inches per second is the "only possible" velocity. Rather, it is used in the sense of "a dose of only 5mg can kill you", which does not mean that a dose of 5g will not kill you.]

> Simple trigonometry led to the conclusion that pushing an object away at two inches per second (a rate easily achievable by an EVA astronaut) within a 30-degree cone centered on a line directly opposite the direction that the ISS was traveling as it orbited the Earth **would be enough**.

The *actual* velocity is two feet per second, which is more than two inches per second, and thus meets the minimum velocity requirement.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! One thought; since we are trying to do something right rather than wrong, I think that a *dose of medicine* is a better analogy than a dose of radiation. And a dose of medicine can certainly have a range of doses that both below and above which undesired things can happen.

Comment: you can mentally replace 'only about' with 'as little as'

Comment: @eps We should not *as a rule* do that. As a rule, technical writing should be clear, and so if something is bounded on the lower side only we can then say 'as little as' if we want, and if it is bounded on both sides, and fairly tightly, we should say 'about'. 'only about' is the same as about; the 'only' simply remarks that the amount is small. At least that's my take on this.

Comment: @uhoh Agreed, *technical* writing should do better. But this is not technical writing, is it? At least the sections you quoted appear to be targeted at the general population, rather than a technical audience.

Comment: @BrianDrake the general public understands the difference between a one-sided limit and a two-sided limit; the difference between "must be greater than x" and "must be about x". An author writing about technical information should not think that it's okay to say something ambiguously when slightly different and equally simple wording can avoid said ambiguity. It's not okay to do something wrong when doing it right isn't any harder, no.