# What steel ball was thrown out of the ISS to help test how well ground stations can track orbital debris?

Tags: iss, identify-this-object, tracking, radar

The question [What kinds of things have been tossed out of the ISS?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17739/12102) has a broken YouTube link. This is why it's good to include at least the name of the video in your post (which I didn't back in 2016). I got it from the Science20 post [Why A Ball Thrown To Earth From Orbit "Boomerangs". Can Astronauts Hit Earth With A Ball, Arrow Or Bullet?](https://www.science20.com/robert_inventor/why_a_ball_thrown_to_earth_from_orbit_boomerangs_can_astronauts_hit_earth_with_a_ball_arrow_or_bullet-158237) where the link is also broken. The (missing) video is introduced as:

> Here is a steel ball thrown out of the ISS to help test how well ground stations can track orbital debris

Any ideas what steel ball this could be, or how I might go about tracking another video of the event down?

Answer (score 5):

The ODERACS (Orbital DEbris RAdar Calibration Spheres):

> Five-centimeter balls were detected by the Don-2N radar with an experimental processing program with incoherent accumulation of about a dozen signals at a target height of 352 km and at a distance of 500-800 km (tracking up to 900-1500 km).

- [ODERACS 2A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODERACS_2A)
- [ODERACS 2B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODERACS_2B)
- [ODERACS 2C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODERACS_2C)
- [ODERACS 2D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODERACS_2D)
- [ODERACS 2E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODERACS_2E)
- Astronautix: [ODERACS](http://www.astronautix.com/o/oderacs.html)
- Gunter's Space Page: [ODERACS](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/oderacs.htm)

Comment: The ODERACS-2 were released from the Shuttle Orbiter on STS-63, not from ISS.

Comment: Downvoted until a reference is provided showing that these were launched from the ISS.

Comment: @OrganicMarble STS-60 in 1994.

Comment: So, not what the question is asking for.

Comment: I'll un-accept the answer at least temporarily since I'm asking for something thrown from the ISS, but I wonder if the author of the article just got it wrong and is actually talking about these and just got mixed up and said "ISS" by accident.

Comment: @uhoh The ODERACS targets were not tossed out by hand from the shuttle on STS-63. They were released from a Getaway Special canister (GAS Can) mounted on a carrier in the payload bay. https://i.imgur.com/YEr0QBG.png They were actually 3 spheres and 3 dipoles.  ODERACS 1 was on STS-60 and released 6 spheres, also from a GAS can.